# Phrase for a vocational college diploma

Tags: phrase-request, translation

A vocational college diploma in Russia contains a sheet where some particular features of your education course are listed: date of enrollment, date of completion, what exams you took to enroll, etc.

One line reads as "Production-work (professional) practice: ______" and looks like this:

[image]

In a particular diploma [being translated by a fellow translator](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=4&MessNum=334900&l1=1&l2=2), this line is filled out this way, in a clumsy translation:

> Production-work practice: **compliant with the speciality profile**

The Russian original is

> Производственная практика: **по профилю специальности**.

The meaning is, the student has passed internship, or, probably more correctly, "industrial placement". He worked for a period of time at a plant. The work that he carried out was "in line with what he was taught at the college".  Maybe if the student's industrial placement was at some plant worthy of specific mention, the particular plant would be named, but what we have is a kind of general-purpose phrase.

What would be an appropriate English phrase to put in that document? Would this fit:

> Industrial placement: **in agreement with the curriculum**.

Comment: I think you mean "internship", not [*internment*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=internment).

Comment: @user3169 - LOL, indeed

Comment: @user3169 - feel free to edit out typos and grammatical mistakes!

Comment: I would suggest "all requirements satisfied"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so you know, "industrial placement" is a British term -- I don't think it's used at all in the United States. I had to look it up, because I never heard it before. Americans use "corporate internship" or "paid internship" to signify work done during or after college. ("Corporate internship" can be either paid or unpaid.)

"In agreement with the curriculum" is OK, but it suggests that a placement can "agree," which is technically something only humans do. I think there's probably a better way to say it.

It's not an easy thing to translate. You're trying to say a lot in just a few words. I think these are decent:

> Industrial placement: corresponding to graduate's specialization
>
> Industrial placement: corresponding to graduate's concentration

If you want to stress that the work was closely related to the major:

> Industrial placement: directly related to graduate's specialization

If you want the diploma to be understood well in the U.S., I'd recommend:

> Corporate internship:

Comment: Thank you! An interesting use of "concentration", I've never come across such use before

Comment: You're welcome! "Concentration" is common in American colleges. It's synonymous with "major." "Concentration" sounds a little more official and lends more gravity than "specialization," but the latter might be more appropriate. If the vocational school has an official curriculum with credits and courses required to graduate (especially multi-year programs), then I think it's perfectly acceptable and maybe even better to use "concentration." Otherwise, "specialization" is fine.

Comment: @Ringo - As a footnote, not all internships are paid internships. A lot of it depends on the field and labor regulations. My daughter attended a vocational school and had to work a summer internship as part of the curriculum. She didn't get paid a dime, but the experience was invaluable, particularly in passing the certification exam.

Comment: @J.R. Right, I think, logically speaking, the way I wrote it isn't technically incorrect, but it's misleading. I'll change it to be more clear.